# My java code often stuck in a loop "while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {". How to optimize the code

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming, java-io

My java code often stuck in a loop "while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {"

I guess it is because java garbage collection did not get back some memory. The variable "line" will point to new content in every iteration and the memory of old content of "line" is not collected back by java GC for some reason.

So How to optimize the code to fix the problem?

The code is as follows:

```
for (String url : urlList) { // a loop that process ~1000 urls
      HttpResponse response = fetchSomeUrl(url);
      // I already confirmed that response code is 200 OK, which means HttpResponse is generated successfully.

      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
      StringBuilder raw_content = new StringBuilder();
      String line;
      int i = 0;
      System.out.println("=====start processing rd.readLine()");
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
         // my code often stuck here when there are more than 1000 lines in rd
         System.out.println("=====processing " + i + "th line");
         raw_content.append(line);
         raw_content.append("\n");
         i++;
      }
      System.out.println("=====finished processing rd.readLine()");
  }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the GC; you're probably stuck waiting for the network.

Comment: How do you know it is stuck, rather than just spending a lot of time in an I/O based loop inside a 1000 iteration outer loop?

Comment: I know it stucks in the inner loop because I added several "System.out.println()" in the code. I can see that it stucks there after printing "=====processing 815 iteration"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My java code often stuck in a loop "while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {"

The word is 'blocked'. It is blocked waiting for another line to arrive from the peer, or for the peer to close the connection.

> I guess it is because java garbage collection did not get back some memory.

It has nothing whatsoever to do with either garbage collection, Java, or memory. It has to do with what the peer is or isn't doing.

> The variable "line" will point to new content in every iteration and the memory of old content of "line" is not collected back by java GC for some reason.

This is nonsense, and even if it was true it wouldn't account for the phenomena.

> So How to optimize the code to fix the problem?

It's not a coding problem, and if it was, no amount of 'optimization' would solve it. Your program is working as coded. This loop will iterate until the peer disconnects, and it will block while there isn't a complete line or end of stream to be read.

You should be processing each line as it arrives, rather than trying to assemble them and process them all when the peer disconnects.

**EDIT** You could consider setting a read timeout to catch problematic cases.

Comment: Thanks, I added a few more lines in the code to make it clearer.  In fact, each iteration in the outer loop processes a different url. As you see in the code, I already generated a httpResponse before I start the inner loop, and the BufferedReader just reads from that httpResponse. So the BufferedReader no longer depends on network connection. Thus  I am not sure why there are cases that there isn't a complete line or end of stream to be read.

Comment: Of course it depends on the network connection. That's where the HTTP response comes from.

Comment: thanks, @EJP. the timeout setting is already set in the fetchSomeUrl() function. What I do not understand is that, since I already confirmed that httpResponse is successfully generated, then there should be no uncertainty from network in this iteration, right?

Comment: Wrong. The `HttpResponse` is only a wrapper for a network connection. All you know when you get it is that you have an HTTP 200 response code, which is on the first line of the response. You don't know that you have the entire response. You're just assuming that, and obviously you're wrong. If you had the whole response, you wouldn't get blocked trying to read it, and as you *are* blocked trying to read it, obviously it hasn't been read already, otherwise *that* would have blocked. I suggest you've set a connect timeout but not a read timeout.

Comment: Oh, I see. I have thought "HTTP 200 response code" means httpResponse is already fetched successfully. As you suggested, seems 200 response code is not enough. It may still break in the middle even if there is a "200" response code...... and my code just waits infinitely for the left part to come... great, thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Your loop will not stop until it reaches the null as the code written.You should add a condition that will tell the program to stop when it reach 1000. And also, your content might be over 1000 than you expected that's why it is stuck.